# How can I solve Fortran runtime error: End of file?

Tags: fortran

I am using **Codeblock 13.12**. My file is not readable. and getting the runtime error

```
program asd
    implicit none
    integer :: x

    open(unit = 2, file = "text.txt")

    read(2,*)x
    write(*,*)x

end program
```

and my **text.txt** file is :

```
1
```

I've seen many answers, but none of them worked for my code

Comment: Can you be specific ... which answers to other similar questions have you tried and with no good results ?  The most likely explanation is that the program is not looking for the file where the file is - have you tried using the `inquire` statement prior to opening the file to check that the file is in the location the program is searching ?

Comment: Can you please help me about ```inquire``` ? I am not familier with it

Comment: Is the line in `text.txt` properly terminated with '\n'?

Comment: @steve there is only one line in **text.txt** file

Comment: And is the line properly terminated? Try to make an empty line after the first one.

Comment: I am not understanding about the **terminated** meaning. Can you please clear it? @VladimirF

Comment: Try to add another empty line. Just press enter in a text editor.

Comment: The line needs to have a newline character for termination.  If the `1` is terminated with EOF (end-of-file), you will get the runtime error because the program reads `1` then reads the next character from the file (because the integer might be 10 or 1231 or 1452 or ...).  For a valid integer, this character is a digit, a comma, or whitespace.  EOF is none of these.

Answer (score 1):

Your program is just fine. As a matter of fact, even if the first line is not properly terminated, gfortran will take the EOF as the EOL and still work.

Your problem is you are working in the IDE CodeBlock. The IDE does not run the program in your working directory so the file text.txt is not where the program is running, hence the end of file error.

Check out this post [Codeblock working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42468635/how-do-i-set-the-working-directory-on-codeblocks-on-mac) which will guide you to solving your problem.