# When I build and run code on CodeBlocks why do I now get a zsh: file or directory not found error?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have written some code in **CodeBlocks**, and when I run it, I get a `zsh: file or directory not found error`. I never used to get this before but after installing Xcode I started getting it. Here is the error log after I click on 'build and run' in CodeBlocks:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: /Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/patrickchong/Desktop/BMLL preparation/C++ tutorial/C++ Tutorial 2/CodeAlong1/bin/Debug/CodeAlong1
```

Any suggestions? Is it related to the code I am running? Thanks!

Here is some details regarding the compiler of my Codeblocks:

[image]

Also to add that my 'executable path' is empty at the moment! Where should this point to?

Comment: I see a relative path, so I'd check the current directory

Comment: Hi MatG, do you mean that I cd into the directory, then 'build and run'?

Comment: I mean, whoever is launching `cb_console_runner` does that from a certain directory, usually the project, check your settings. Alternatively, use absolute paths

Comment: Thanks Mat, I have tried a few things but couldn't get it to work. I have added some more details in the description above, do you mean I need to change the 'toolchain' path?

Comment: Have you checked other [answers like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42469973/7143595)? Check also Project > Properties > Build Target > Execution Working Directory

Comment: Hi Mat, thanks for the link, it appears that the Execution Working Directory just has a '.' by default. Where should this be pointing to? Is it the directory where my Codeblocks script is saved? Because I tried this and I still get the same error!